# How to access a key in JSON file which is FHIR complaint using c#?

Tags: c#, json

I have below input json and I need to access `effectiveDateTime` key and update the value with current date using c#.

```
"Observation": {
        "resourceType": "Bundle",
        "type": "collection",
        "entry": [
            {
                "resource": {
                    "resourceType": "Observation",
                    "code": {
                        "coding": [
                            {
                                "system": "LN",
                                "code": "8480-6"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    "valueQuantity": {
                        "value": "151"
                    },
                    "effectiveDateTime": "2016-02-24"
                }
            }
        ]
    },
```

Comment: Do you mistake us for your coding slaves? Stackoverflow for a code writing service? Bad news - we are not. You want hints - great. You want debugging help - great. We want you to attempt to use your brain and show us what you have tried. And we answer questions which you lack - what you WANT is irrelevant if you do not ask a concrete specific question.

Comment: Absolutely not, I'm just seeking help. Thanks.

Comment: I was not sure how to traverse in a nested json structure, hence seeking help.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a class type for this.
2. Deserialized Json value.
3. Update your "effectiveDateTime" from this class.
4. Serialized this class back to Json type.

Answer (score 0):

Read up on, and use a Json Seralizer/DeSerializer.
I recommend Newtonsoft Json.Net.

[Deserialize an Object with Json.Net](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/deserializeobject.htm)